# Blank jasper report is generated in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        con = DbConnection.getConnection();
        JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("outstanding.jrxml");

        String sql = "Select id, cust_name, day, location, total, advance, outstanding from atharwa.project where id='" + txtcheck.getText() + "' ";
        JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
        newQuery.setText(sql);
        jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, con);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this enough info to re-create the problem? should we not have at least "outstanding.jrxml" also?

Comment: i havnt edited jrxml file..but i deleted it and opened new report wizard and i am done, i think , i had done something wrong in previous one.

Comment: can you tell me one thing please?

Comment: when we take a new report wizard, it asks for one query, and there is also one option below to design the query. but we fire a query generally from our jFrame coding like on button event or any other, so actually it generates reports according to our coding in event not that query which we have entered previously while starting that wizard, so why does it ask there a query? does not it conflict there? suppose we entered two different queries?